# How to capture stdout of a Python script executed with pythonw?

Tags: python

When a script is executed with `pythonw` it will not open a console.

Is there a way to capture the `stdout` of such a script by keeping the usage of `pythonw`?

Note, I am looking for a solution that does not require the modification of the script (I know that I can use logging)

Update: `pythonw script.py >somefile` seems to work. How can I redirect it to console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was obvious: `pythonw script.py|more`

Answer (score 1):

If you can change how you invoke it (as you do in the update), why don't you just run it with python instead of pythonw?

```
python script.py
```

Comment: `pythonw` executes scripts in a different context and sometimes the scrip will behave different.

Comment: Seems like an odd thing for the script to do, but that's true I suppose.

Comment: Stop thinking about scripts as console-scripts, a python script can be a fully GUI application ;)

Comment: I realise that! :) What wasn't clear (to me) in your q. is that you aren't running the pythonw command in a console. But your solution makes sense.